# Prime sums in a 4 x 4 board

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-theory

Place the integers 1 to 16 in the sixteen cells of a 4 x 4 board so that the sum of any four numbers in a row or column is a different prime.

Comment: Bernardo may be if you add a condition where diagonals must also add to Prime numbers it could be a unique solution?? Not sure it exists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one solution I found by hand:

> ```
>   1  2  3  5  = 11
>   4  6  8 13  = 31
>   7  9 10 15  = 41
>  11 12 16 14  = 53
>   =  =  =  =
>  23 29 37 47
> ```

This is how I found it:

> I first worked out which primes to use. I needed to find two disjoint sets of four primes that had an average of 34, the 4x4 magic number. I made a list as follows:
>
> ```
>   p    p-34
>  11  -23
>  13  -21
>  17  -17
>  19  -15
>  23  -11
>  29  -5
>  31  -3
>  --34
>  37  +3
>  41  +7
>  43  +9
>  47  +13
>  53  +19
>  59  +25
>  61  +27
> ```
>
> Then I made pairs of primes, one pair both below 34 or and one pair above 34, with matching surplus/deficits:
>
> ```
>  16) 29+23                 + 41+43 / 37+47
>  20) 29+19 / 31+17         + 41+47
>  22) 29+17                 + 37+53 / 43+47
>  26) 31+11 / 29+13 / 19+23 + 41+53
> ```
>
> From these I chose two disjoint sets of 4: 29+23 + 37+47, and 31+11 + 41+53. One set are the row sums, the other the column sums. The order does not matter as you can reorder the rows. Then I made a little excel sheet to keep track of the sums as I placed the 16 numbers.

For completeness, I wrote a computer program and below are all 28 solutions it found. There are three sets of row/column sum primes that can occur.

> ```
>   1  2  3  5 = 11    1  2  3  5 = 11    1  2  3  5 = 11    1  2  3  5 = 11
>   4  6  7 14 = 31    4  7  9 11 = 31    4  6  9 12 = 31    7  4  8 12 = 31
>   8  9 11 13 = 41    8  6 12 15 = 41    7  8 10 16 = 41    6 10 11 14 = 41
>  10 12 16 15 = 53   10 14 13 16 = 53   11 13 15 14 = 53    9 13 15 16 = 53
>   =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =
>  23 29 37 47        23 29 37 47        23 29 37 47        23 29 37 47
>
>   1  2  3  5 = 11    1  2  3  5 = 11    1  2  3  5 = 11    3  1  2  5 = 11
>   4  6  8 13 = 31    4  9  7 11 = 31    4  6 13  8 = 31    4  7  9 11 = 31
>   7  9 10 15 = 41    8 12  6 15 = 41    7  9 15 10 = 41    6  8 12 15 = 41
>  11 12 16 14 = 53   10 14 13 16 = 53   11 12 16 14 = 53   10 13 14 16 = 53
>   =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =
>  23 29 37 47        23 37 29 47        23 29 47 37        23 29 37 47
>
>
>   1  3  6  7 = 17    1  2  6  8 = 17
>   2  4  8  9 = 23    3  4  7  9 = 23
>   5 10 13 15 = 43    5 11 13 14 = 43
>  11 12 14 16 = 53   10 12 15 16 = 53
>   =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =
>  19 29 41 47        19 29 41 47
>
>
>   1  3  9 10 = 23    1  3  9 10 = 23    1  3  9 10 = 23    1  2  9 11 = 23
>   2  4 11 12 = 29    2  4 11 12 = 29    2  4 11 12 = 29    3  4 10 12 = 29
>   6  5 14 16 = 41    8  5 13 15 = 41    6  7 13 15 = 41    5  7 13 16 = 41
>   8  7 13 15 = 43    6  7 14 16 = 43    8  5 14 16 = 43    8  6 15 14 = 43
>   =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =
>  17 19 47 53        17 19 47 53        17 19 47 53        17 19 47 53
>
>   1  2  9 11 = 23    1  2  9 11 = 23    1  2  9 11 = 23    1  2  9 11 = 23
>   3  4 10 12 = 29    3  4 10 12 = 29    3  4 10 12 = 29    3  4 10 12 = 29
>   5  7 15 14 = 41    6  8 13 14 = 41    8  6 13 14 = 41    7  5 15 14 = 41
>   8  6 13 16 = 43    7  5 15 16 = 43    5  7 15 16 = 43    6  8 13 16 = 43
>   =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =
>  17 19 47 53        17 19 47 53        17 19 47 53        17 19 47 53
>
>   1  2  9 11 = 23    2  1  9 11 = 23    2  1  9 11 = 23    2  1  9 11 = 23
>   3  4 10 12 = 29    4  3 10 12 = 29    4  3 10 12 = 29    4  3 10 12 = 29
>   7  5 13 16 = 41    5  7 15 14 = 41    5  7 13 16 = 41    6  8 13 14 = 41
>   6  8 15 14 = 43    6  8 13 16 = 43    6  8 15 14 = 43    5  7 15 16 = 43
>   =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =
>  17 19 47 53        17 19 47 53        17 19 47 53        17 19 47 53
>
>   1  3  9 10 = 23    1  3  9 10 = 23    1  3  9 10 = 23    3  1  9 10 = 23
>   4  2 11 12 = 29    4  2 11 12 = 29    4  2 11 12 = 29    2  4 11 12 = 29
>   5  6 14 16 = 41    7  6 13 15 = 41    5  8 13 15 = 41    5  6 14 16 = 41
>   7  8 13 15 = 43    5  8 14 16 = 43    7  6 14 16 = 43    7  8 13 15 = 43
>   =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =
>  17 19 47 53        17 19 47 53        17 19 47 53        17 19 47 53
>
>   3  1  9 10 = 23    3  1  9 10 = 23
>   2  4 11 12 = 29    2  4 11 12 = 29
>   7  6 13 15 = 41    5  8 13 15 = 41
>   5  8 14 16 = 43    7  6 14 16 = 43
>   =  =  =  =         =  =  =  =
>  17 19 47 53        17 19 47 53
> ```

By reordering rows or columns it is even possible to let the two diagonals be two other primes, different to the row/column sums. My program found 44 such solutions. Here is just one:

> ```
>              /31
>   3  7  1  6 = 17
>  10 15  5 13 = 43
>  12 16 11 14 = 53
>   4  9  2  8 = 23
>   =  =  =  = \
>  29 47 19 41  37
> ```

And finally, here are solutions for 5x5, 6x6, 7x7 squares:

> ```
>    1  2  3  4  7  = 17
>    5  6  8  9 13  = 41
>   10 11 12 14 20  = 67
>   15 24 17 25 16  = 97
>   22 18 19 21 23  = 103
>    =  =  =  =  =
>   53 61 59 73 79
>  
>    1   2   3   4   5   8  = 23
>    6   7   9  10  11  16  = 59
>   12  13  14  15  17  18  = 89
>   19  20  21  22  23  26  = 131
>   24  27  29  28  32  33  = 173
>   35  34  31  30  25  36  = 191
>    =   =   =   =   =   =
>   97 103 107 109 113 137
>  
>    1   2   3   4   5   6   8  = 29
>    7   9  10  11  12  13  17  = 79
>   14  15  16  18  19  20  25  = 127
>   21  22  23  24  26  27  30  = 173
>   28  29  31  32  33  34  36  = 223
>   35  37  38  42  39  49  41  = 281
>   45  43  46  48  47  44  40  = 313
>    =   =   =   =   =   =   =
>  151 157 167 179 181 193 197
> ```

Comment: Any other solutions?

Comment: What about the 5 x 5 case with integers 1 to 25?

Comment: I don't know if there are other sets of primes, Once I found the ones I used I didn't look further. There are other solutions to the square, e.g. swap 3 and 5 as well as 14 and 16, but probably not very many.

Comment: Interestingly, this also has a prime sum on the diagonal. Maybe requiring that makes the puzzle unique?

Comment: @Typhon: According to my computer program there are 44 solutions where the rows, columns, and main diagonals add up to distinct prime numbers. I have edited my answer to show one of them.

Answer (score 2):

There are too many solutions, so I have showns a few of them then stopped:

1:

> $\begin{bmatrix}
> 1& 2 &7  &3 \\ 
> 6 & 11 &9  &5 \\ 
> 8 &12  &16  &13 \\ 
> 10 & 4 & 15 &14 
> \end{bmatrix}$

2:

> $\begin{bmatrix}
> 1& 2 &7  &3 \\ 
> 6 & 11 &9  &5 \\ 
> 8 &12  &16  &13 \\ 
> 14 & 10 & 15 &4 
> \end{bmatrix}$

3:

> $\begin{bmatrix}
> 2& 5 &1  &7 \\ 
> 3 & 6 &9  &11 \\ 
> 8 &12  &16  &13 \\ 
> 10 & 14 & 15 &4 
> \end{bmatrix}$

4:

> $\begin{bmatrix}
> 2& 5 &7  &1 \\ 
> 3 & 6 &9  &11 \\ 
> 8 &12  &16  &13 \\ 
> 4 & 14 & 15 &10
> \end{bmatrix}$

5:

> $\begin{bmatrix}
> 3& 1 &2  &7 \\ 
> 4 & 5 &9  &11 \\ 
> 6 &12  &8  &15 \\ 
> 10 & 13 & 16 &14
> \end{bmatrix}$

6:

> $\begin{bmatrix}
> 3& 1 &2  &7 \\ 
> 4 & 9 &5  &11 \\ 
> 6 &12  &8  &15 \\ 
> 10 & 13 & 16 &14
> \end{bmatrix}$

7:

> $\begin{bmatrix}
> 1& 2 &4  &6 \\ 
> 3 & 5 &7  &8 \\ 
> 10 &9  &12  &16 \\ 
> 11 & 15 & 14 &13
> \end{bmatrix}$

8:

> $\begin{bmatrix}
> 1& 2 &4  &6 \\ 
> 3 & 5 &7  &8 \\ 
> 12 &9  &10  &16 \\ 
> 13 & 15 & 14 &11
> \end{bmatrix}$

9:

> $\begin{bmatrix}
> 1& 2 &4  &6 \\ 
> 3 & 5 &7  &8 \\ 
> 12 &9  &10  &16 \\ 
> 13 & 15 & 14 &11
> \end{bmatrix}$

10:

> $\begin{bmatrix}
> 1& 2 &4  &8 \\ 
> 3 & 6 &11  &5 \\ 
> 9 &15  &7  &12 \\ 
> 10 & 14 & 13 &16
> \end{bmatrix}$

10:

> $\begin{bmatrix}
> 1& 2 &5  &3 \\ 
> 4 & 8 &7  &6 \\ 
> 11 &12  &14  &10 \\ 
> 13 & 9 & 15 &16
> \end{bmatrix}$

I think there are too many solutions, so I stopped :)

Comment: Hmm. The solution I found is not among these, as none of them have a row or column with 1+2+3+5=11.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis still updating :)

Comment: The last two of your solutions have a row sum of 25, which is not a prime. I get only 28 solutions, excluding row/column permutations.

Comment: Oray is there a solution where diagonals also add up to Prime numbers? That could be unique

Comment: @DeepakMahulikar According to my computer program there are 44 solutions where the rows, columns, and diagonals add up to distinct prime numbers. One of them is shown in my answer.